# How can I set a replacement for the javac shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell, ant, javac

When I run Maven or Ant build system, I want to get all the arguments for javac including the file name, and dump all the arguments to a file.
So I found this scripts (name of this scripts is javacdump.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$INF_ARGS" = "" ];
then
    echo "You must set the INF_ARGS environment variable to a file you wish the arguments to be dumped into."
    exit 1
fi
echo "" >> $INF_ARGS 
echo "---" >> $INF_ARGS
echo $* >> $INF_ARGS
cat ${1:1} >> $INF_ARGS
echo "---" >> $INF_ARGS
echo "" >> $INF_ARGS
javac $*
```

This scripts works if I run "source javacdump.sh test.java"
The file indicated by INF_ARGS can contain "test.java".
So How can I use this for the build system like Ant?  How can I set this script as a replacement for the javac shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Build systems aren't concerned with building files one at a time as it looks like you're doing. It's about building entire projects. You can use the *debug* option with either Ant or Maven to see the full *command line* output of the build.

Ant and Maven is about building constantly and repeatably. You set your arguments once and build over and over again -- building all the sources at once.

I'm not going into details on how to use the `<javac/>` task in Ant or the `<build>` entity section in Maven to tune your build. It's too complex to give as a single Stack Overflow answer. Go to the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) or the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) webpages to learn more.